# HIghlight Active Link in the Navbar , React

Tags: reactjs, react-router

This is a simple version of the problem not the actual problem.
React code:

```
<Router>
   <Navbar/>
   <Routes>
       <Route path="/:genreId" element={<MovieList/>} />
   <Routes>
<Router>
```

This problem is that in the Navbar, I have several button to go the particular genre.
I want to highlight active button  in the Navbar (when I click "comedy" the "comedy" button should be lit up)

some solutions

1. State => will not work if I reload
2. Session Storage => will not work if I come be website for the first time
3. Extract the params using the useParams Hook => this will not work since param "genreId" is available to the movieList component not the navbar
4. Extract from the window.location => Don't want to do it since it look too ad-hock

What is the right method?

Comment: Try using redux store. Save the selected tab info into your redux store and access it. Since your use case is to persist the data on page reload please use  `redux-presist` https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-persist .

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest #3 "Extract the params using the useParams Hook => this will not work since param "genreId" is available to the movieList component not the navbar". You are correct though, this doesn't work since the `Navbar` component is rendered *outside* the `Routes` component and won't have access to the currently matched route. To resolve this you should move the `Navbar` component *inside* the `Routes` component. To make this work you'll create a layout route component that renders the `Navbar` component and an `Outlet` component for nested routes to render their `element` prop into.

Example:

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const Layout = () => (
  <>
    <Navbar />
    <Outlet />
  </>
);
```

Then render the `MovieList` route as a nested route of the layout route.

```
<Routes>
  <Route element={<Layout />}>
    <Route path="/:genreId" element={<MovieList />} />
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

The `Navbar` component can now safely access the `genreId` route path param and use it to apply any logic necessary to mark a button as "active. Here's a simple example:

```
const genres = ["action", "comedy", "drama"];

const Navbar = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { genreId } = useParams();

  const navigateTo = (genreId) =>
    navigate(generatePath("/:genreId", { genreId }));

  return (
    <>
      {genres.map((genre) => (
        <button
          key={genre}
          className={["genreButton", genreId === genre && "active"]
            .filter(Boolean)
            .join(" ")}
          type="button"
          onClick={() => navigateTo(genre)}
        >
          {genre}
        </button>
      ))}
    </>
  );
};
```

[image]

[image: Edit highlight-active-link-in-the-navbar-react]

Comment: thanks champ, my problem is not solved

Comment: @so_hell What issue still remains? Can you share your `Navbar` component as part of a [mcve]?

Answer (score 1):

try `useLocation` hook in `react-router-dom`.

It's kind of similar the solution with
"4.Extract from the window.location => Don't want to do it since it look too ad-hock",

by using this hook, it is not so "ad-hock".

```
import { Link, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
const currentPage = useLocation().pathname;

<Link 
  key={1} 
  className={currentPage === '/' ? 'nav-link active' : 'nav-link'} 
  to="/"
>
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually use IndexDB for that kind of stuff. To manage the IndexDB perfectly you can use localforage. You can check this link.[localforage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/localforage)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use NavLink instead of Link to design the active route. Here is the [documentation](https://reactrouter.com/en/v6.3.0/upgrading/v5#rename-navlink-exact-to-navlink-end).

```
    <Router>
       <Navbar/>
       <Routes>
           <Route path="/:genreId" element={<MovieList/>} />
       <Routes>
    <Router>
```

In the Navbar component you can write like this to have the active link:

```
   <nav>
      <NavLink to="/:genreId">Genre Name</NavLink>
   </nav>
```